# How can i include a jquery script that can manipulate user interface in sugar CRM 7.5?

Tags: sugarcrm

I have recently upgraded a sugar CRM version 6.5.x to 7.5.0.1

In the old version we have used jquery script to show/hide various input entry's in create record/edit record in oppportunity module for custom requirement.

Scripts reside in /custom/include/javascript/myscript.js

Now this script is not working in 7.5 instance.

How can i include a jquery script that can manipulate user interface in sugar CRM 7.5?

Answer (score 0):

You have to redesign the script according to Sugar 7

- You can make your fields dependent if you only want to show hide the fields [Ref](http://support.sugarcrm.com/04_Knowledge_Base/02Administration/100Studio_and_Module_Builder/Sugar_Logic/Dependent_Field__Display_Based_on_List_Values/)
- You can register your events in initialize function of record view controller file of your module see the sample code.

> this.on('field_name', this.functionName, this);

Now you have to handle events in controller file of your view.